# How to automatically close an OK window in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I need to automatically close an "OK" window in a program by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I tried to do that with a VBScript, but it gives me an error.

```
Set objshell = WshShell.Sendkeys "{Enter}" ("wscript.shell")
objshell.Run,0, True
exit
```

The error is:

> Line: 1
>   Char: 34
>   Error: End of instruction expected
>   Code: 800A0401
>   Source: Microsoft Vbscript Compile Error

Comment: ..and the error is? This script just presses enter. Maybe you should try AutoIt instead

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//8c6yea83%28v%3dvs.85%29). There is no intrinsic object `WshShell` in VBScript. You need to create a `WScript.Shell` instance and assign it to that variable before you can call the `SendKeys` method on it.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

And you probably need to bring the window to which you're trying to send that keystroke to the front first using [`AppActivate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//wzcddbek%28v%3dvs.85%29).

Anyway, seeing how all of your 3 lines of code are entirely broken syntactically, I ***strongly*** recommend you go find a VBScript tutorial before proceeding any further.

Note also that `SendKeys` is a *horribly* unreliable method of automation. You may want to look into something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am not a programmer I just need this script to perform a simple task in my service network. Would it be possible for you to write a correct script that a could use? I would very much appreciate it. Please. I tried this two lines you wrote and it stops the error, but didn't perform the required task

Comment: @Paulo SO is a site where programmers and programming enthusiasts share their knowledge. If you're just looking for someone to write code for you this is not the right place for you.

Comment: Thank you Sir I'll keep that in mind you're a very nice person... BTW i'm sure that I can fit in the programming enthusiasts ... At least I'm trying...